# How to enable Service Worker only for HTML requests?

Tags: javascript, service-worker, cloudflare-workers

I am developing the code for a Service Worker using Cloudflare Workers (JS).
I want to fire the Service Worker only for HTML requests, so that I can optimize the number of requests being evaluated. Right now I am using this code:

```
addEventListener('fetch', async event => {
 if (event.request.method === 'GET' && event.request.headers.get('accept').includes('text/html')) {
  event.respondWith(handleRequest(event.request));
 }
});

async function handleRequest(request) {
  const response = await fetch(request);

  // Clone the response so that it's no longer immutable
  const newResponse = new Response(response.body, response);

  // Add a custom header with a value
  newResponse.headers.append('x-h-w', 'hello world');

  return newResponse;

}
```

While it is only adding the custom header to the request associated with the HTML element, the Service Worker is evaluating every request from the website (styles, images, scripts etc.).

Is there a way to evaluate only HTML requests? (without consuming quota evaluating the other type of requests)

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible, I fear. As soon as you add an event listener on the "fetch" event, you'll receive all events. But just not invoking the `event.respondWith` is the right thing to do if you are not interested.

Why would you be worried about the "quota"? You should not notice the performance impact or can you really measure any difference?

As a tiny hint: You don't need to check the "accept" header, because only the initial request is usually an HTML request and this request has some special mode:

```js
event.request.mode === 'navigate'
```

This should be even less performance overhead

Comment: The reason why I am worried about the quota is because Cloudflare, on its free plan allows 100,000 requests/day. A normal Wordpress website is loading an average of 25-30 requests per page load (html, styles, images, scripts) etc. - If I only need to evaluate the 1st request (html), to get the request IP (and apply some logic), it's a waste of resources to evaluate the other requests.

Comment: But the service worker code is executed on client site. So the amount of requests against Cloudflare should not be affected by this at all. The service worker allows you basically to intercept the requests as a kind of middleware. Not doing more requests and only running on the client machine. Slowing down mostly the user device. Not your backends.

Comment: Cloudflare charges for every invocation a Worker makes. Apparently, there is no way to only invoke the Cloudflare Worker on a specific type of request (html resource). I am not talking about performance here, but costs.

Comment: ok. But my point is: If the client loads the HTML he doesn't do any request to Cloudflare after the service worker was installed. Only in the moment your service worker does `const response = await fetch(request);` the request against Cloudflare is done. So in the end it is exactly the same amount of requests against Cloudflare. With or without service worker. Maybe you are loading in the "init" phase of your service worker an additional HTML for caching? But otherwise, I still don't see why the amount of requests should be higher with your above code.

Comment: Cloudflare does not charge for requests on a proxied domain. Cloudflare charges for requests to Workers (with a free tier of 100K/day requests). That's the main difference here.

Comment: ok. Then I might be mistaken, but actually sounds like a weird pricing policy 

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248046/discussion-between-alex-and-viktor-luft).